# Showing the supremum of a ratio of quadratic forms doesnt depend on a plane

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization

Let $(a \in \mathbb{R}^p)$ and let $(\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p})$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. Prove that

$$
\sup_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{R}^p}} \left(\frac{(x^T a)^{2}}{x^T \Sigma x}\right) = \sup_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{R}^p \\ (x^T v) = c}} \frac{(x^T a)^2}{x^T \Sigma x}
$$

for any vector $(v \in \mathbb{R}^p)$ and any scalar $(c \neq 0)$.

I am currently lost as how to solve this, i tried using Lagrange Multipliers but could not factor out x when i took the first derivative. does anyone have any ideas on how i can prove the equivalence of the two statements